# Ionic 2/3 Variable Access

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using the tutorial below to build out an in-app purchase.

https://github.com/thielCole/ionic-iap2/blob/master/src/pages/about/about.ts

I'm trying to have googleProductID be equal to the googleProductID in my GET call (in the 'content' array)

```
public product: any = {
   name: 'Quiz',
   appleProductID: '1234',
   googleProductID: this.content[0]['googleProductID'],
 };
```

I keep receiving this error...

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Everything matches up in the GET call - Am I having a syntax error or is it unable to make calls here?

***** **EDIT** *******

I'm passing data from one page to another. I'm using an IonViewWillLoad passing the content from the GET call.

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
      this.content = this.navParams.get('content');
      this.gameGear = this.navParams.get('gameGear');
}
```

Comment: Your 'array' this.content is undefined, that's why it can't ready property '0' from it. It seems that you create your product object in a component and most probably this.content didn't receive any value yet. Update your question please.

Comment: Updated the question - Is the "ionViewWillLoad" not loading before the GET call contents? @AndrewRadulescu

Comment: if you are sending data as nav params, it will be available in constructor also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you finish your work take a look at Javascript Hoisting [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-hoisting-in-details/) to understand how the interpreter is reading/transforming the code.

Basically, your variable is first declared, is initialized, moving declarations to the top and after all **ionViewDidLoad** is invoked(example).

```
public product: any = {
    name: 'Quiz',
    appleProductID: '1234',
    googleProductID: undefined
};
```

when you retrieve it from navParams you can update your object

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
      this.content = this.navParams.get('content');
      // Now you have the value 
      this.product.googleProductId = this.content[0]['googleProductID'],
      this.gameGear = this.navParams.get('gameGear');
}
```